# XSLT select text and tags after some elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

this might sound easy problem to you, but somehow Im stuck with it, here is the scenario, I have an xml doc that looks smth like:

```
<doc>
<id>25147</id>
<article>Peggy Lee</article>
<url>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peggy_Lee</url>
Peggy Lee (May 26, 1920 – January 21, 2002) was an <a href="United_States">American</a> <a href="Jazz">jazz</a> and ...
</doc>
```

Now, I'm interested to select the text such as Peggy Lee...., plust the a href tags and all other tags, but not , nor article and other previous tags, as I've selected those before.  Any solution?

So the **output** should be:

```
 Peggy Lee (May 26, 1920 – January 21, 2002) was an <a href="United_States">American</a> <a href="Jazz">jazz</a> and ...
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
 <xsl:copy-of select="url/following::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```